# How to read a timestamp

Tags: user-interface, timestamp

I have joined in a Data competition for students. They gave me timestamps of users' interaction. Is it useful?
Some of them are:
1615983880510

1615767552552

1615767577100

1616036788631

Comment: Check out https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is a linux timestamp. It's actually a pretty interesting time representation. In short, it's just a number. And it represents the total number of seconds that have passed since January 1st 1970. A date known as "Unix Epoch Time".

Now, if you want to convert that into a readable date there are many ways to do it in basically every programing language. For example in python you might do something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def printdate(unix):
  print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

BUT! It seems like your dates might actually be in miliseconds. Meaning that you might actually want to divide your dates by 1000 before passing them trough the function. So...

```py
def printdatems(unix):
  return printdate(unix/1000)
```

And there you go!

```py
printdatems(1615983880510) #2021-03-17 12:24:40
printdatems(1615767552552) #2021-03-15 00:19:12
printdatems(1615767577100) #2021-03-15 00:19:37
printdatems(1616036788631) #2021-03-18 03:06:28
```

That's the output for the example dates you provided.
Of course you can find much more information on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

It's an intresting read!